# Rails Request override params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rack

I need to override `params[:lang]` throughout my entire application from `en` to `us-english`. From the url it should be `en` but within my entire application it needs to be `us-english`, when I then create urls I need it to be converted from `us-english` to `en` again.

I realize that the practical solution would be to just update the url to reflect the actual application but this decision is out of my control.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a better way to handle this? Why can't you use `en`? When do you want it overridden, what problem are you trying to solve? You need to provide more details if you want to get help.

Comment: look into rails i18n fallbacks, if this sounds like the real problem

Answer (score 2):

In the application controller:

```
before_filter :override_params


def override_params
  params[:lang] = 'us' if params[:lang] == 'en'
end


def render( *args )
  params[:lang] = 'en' if params[:lang] == 'us'
  super
 end
```

Although, as Andrew commented, there may be better way s to accomplish what you are trying to achieve,

Comment: That would mean that any `param[:lang]` becomes `us`. Also not sure if that responds to the issue of urls, but I think he'd need to manually specify the lang param each time anyway since most `link_to` etc. aren't going to include params by default...

Comment: Yeah, you're right -I missed that part. I've updated the answer to account for that requirement. I assume that the en is coming from the url, but who knows...

Comment: I got this far but this does not solve the larger problem of then updating created urls to reflect the reversed logic.